# Discrete Logarithm: What does it mean to find the discrete logarithm of $a$ to base $g$ modulo $p$?

Tags: diffie-hellman, discrete-logarithm, modular-arithmetic

My understanding is that $a=g^x\bmod p$ is the discrete logarithm problem. Given the question is worded this way, are we trying to find $x=\log_g a\bmod p$ ?

For instance, if we are trying to compute the discrete logarithm of $3$ to base $2$ - given that $p=11$, what would be the output (or the equation)

---

How would we attempt to solve that problem in Diffie-Hellman ?

<sup>moderator note: that apocryphal extension of the original question came by way of merging with another question.</sup>

Comment: Thanks. Yeah it kinda is - after lectures we have questions to try out on our own :) I'm just not sure how to interpret the question. 
Since the base is 2, we are raising 2 to 3. In other words:
$$2^3 \equiv 8 \mod 11 \equiv 8$$
8 is what we are looking for.

For some reason I was thinking about it another way, $\log_2 3 \equiv \alpha \mod 11$ and we are looking for $\alpha$...Though this way doesn't feel right as you already know the value of LHS - nor does it make much sense as the result of the logarithm has a fractional part.

Comment: The fact that this is a hard problem is literally the reason Diffie-Hellman is secure.

Comment: I understand that practically it is very difficult to obtain a, but I just want to know how to apply modulo inverse on this without using any numbers.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard's_rho_algorithm

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Discrete Log for arbitrary Groups**: Discrete Log can be defined in arbitrary groups and some groups can have an easy solution ([powers of 10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm#Powers_of_10)) and some can have a hard solution.

Let $G$ be any group and $\odot$ be the group operation. For any $k \in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}$, let $g \in G$ then we define $[k]g =  \overbrace{g\odot\cdots\odot g}^{{k\hbox{ - }times}} $. Then for a given $a \in G$ the $k$ that satisfies $[k]b = a$ is called discrete log of $a$ to base $g$. It can also be written as $k = \log_g a$

- **Additive DLog :** The analogous definition for $(\mathbb{Z}_p,+)$ is well-defined with given $a,g,n$ find $x>0$ such that $x g \equiv a \bmod n$. It can be **solved easily**  if you find the inverse of $a$ by using the [Ext-GCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) algorithm.
- **Multiplicative DLog :**, the discrete Logarithm Problem (DLP) is given $a,g,n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ find $x \in \mathbb{Z}_{>1}$ such that $a^x \equiv g \bmod n$, if such $x$ exists.

For the small modulus we can build a table for the DLP problem, or you can stop building the table whenever you find your case.

The below is a DLog (Discrete Log) table for modulus 19 with base 2.

\begin{array}{c|rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr}
x&  1& 2& 3& 4& 5& 6& 7& 8& 9& 10& 11& 12& \color{red}{13}& 14& 15& 16& 17& 18\\ \hline
2 ^x \bmod 19&  2& 4& 8& 16& 13& 7& 14& 9& 18& 17& 15& 11& \color{red}{3}& 6& 12& 5& 10& 1
 \end{array}

For example, given 3 as the DLog base 2 modulo 19, we will look for 3 in the second row and corresponding $x$ in the first row that is 13. I.e. $2^{13} \equiv 3 \bmod 19$

Different bases will produce different tables; for base 5:

\begin{array}{c|rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr}
x&  1& 2& 3& 4& 5& 6& 7& 8& 9& 10& 11& 12& 13& 14& 15& 16& 17& 18\\ \hline
5 ^x \bmod 19&  5& 6& 11& 17& 9& 7& 16& 4& 1& 5& 6& 11& 17& 9& 7& 16& 4& 1
\end{array} If you know the relation with the two bases then you don't need to calculate another base.

This approach is actually brute-forcing and has $\mathcal{O}(n)$- time complexity.

The brute-forcing approach will fail around when $n \approx 2^{80}$. There are better search algorithms for DLOG, the [generic](https://www.shoup.net/papers/dlbounds1.pdf) algorithms that work for any group;

- Shank's [Baby-Step Giant-Step](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baby-step_giant-step) method with $\mathcal{O}(\sqrt{n}\log n)$-time and $\mathcal{O}(\sqrt{n})$-space.
- [Pollard's $\rho$ method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_rho_algorithm_for_logarithms) with $\mathcal{O}(\sqrt{n})$-time is improved version of Shank's method.
- [Pollard's $\lambda$ method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_kangaroo_algorithm) (wild and tame kangoroos)
- [Adleman's index calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_calculus_algorithm) with $\mathcal{O}(\exp(c \sqrt{\log n \log\log n}))$
- [Gordon's NFS algorithm](https://dmgordon.org/papers/crypto_dlog.pdf) with $\mathcal{O}(\exp(c(\log n)^{1/3}(\log\log(n)^{2/3})$-time

and

- [Pohlig–Hellman algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pohlig%E2%80%93Hellman_algorithm) that is applicable when the order of the group is [smooth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smooth_integer). It has  $\mathcal O\left(\sum_i {e_i(\log n+\sqrt {p_i})}\right)$-time complexity where $\prod_i p_i^{e_i}$ is the prime factorization of group order $n$. To mitigate this attack this attack a prime order must be selected than is has same worst-case complexity as $\mathcal{O}(\sqrt{n}\log n)$-time.

---

- **DLog for Elliptic Curves (Additive):** DLOG is also defined for Elliptic Curves ( form an abelian group via point addition), in which given a base point $G$ and another point $Q$ find $x$ such that $[x]G = Q$ where $$[x]G = \overbrace{G+\cdots+G}^{{x\hbox{ - }times}}$$

Dlog is [not hard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic-curve_cryptography#Domain_parameters) for every EC like curves with $|E(\mathbb{F}_q)|=q$. In [Elliptic Curve Cryptography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic-curve_cryptography), we use curves where the Dlog is hard.

Some of the above generic algorithms, Pollard's $\rho$, Pollard's $\lambda$ also apply for DLog for Elliptic Curves, [except](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/8301/18298) index calculus-based algorithms and NFS. The [records on finding DLog on EC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm_records#Elliptic_curves) mostly based on parallel Pollard's $\rho$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, finding the discrete logarithm of $a$ to base $g$ modulo $p$ is solving for $x$ the equation $a=g^x\bmod p$ given integers $g$ (the base), $p$ (the modulus), and $a$ (which discrete logarithm $x$ is thought). That's known as the [Discrete Logarithm Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm) (modulo $p$).

The discrete logarithm of $a=3$ to base $g=2$ modulo $p=11$ is thus $x=8$, because $2^8=256=23\times11+3$ thus $2^8\bmod11=3$ [*not* because $2^3=8$ thus $2^3\bmod11=8$, which happens to also hold].

The security of the original [Diffie-Hellman Key Exchange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange) (using multiplication modulo $p$ as the group operation) requires that it's practically impossible to solve that problem. In practice, parameters $g$ and $p$, and the range in which $x$ is chosen secretly and at random before $a$ is computed as $g^x\bmod p$, are such that the DLP is intractable!

I'll discuss, from the ground up, what that problem is: and some standard methods to attempt to solve it. At first I'll only assume $p\in\mathbb N\setminus\{0,1,2\}$ and $g\in[1,p)$.

#### Definition: what's $g^x\bmod p$

For any $x\in\mathbb N$, by definition of $g^x$, that's $\underbrace {g\cdot g\ldots g}_{x\text{ terms }g}$, with $g^x=1$ when $x=0$ (since $g\ne 0$). That value $g^x$ is an integer (since $g$ is an integer).

And, by definition of the operator$\bmod$ (when there's neither an opening parenthesis immediately on it's left, nor a negative power in it's left operand), $g^x\bmod p$ is the uniquely defined $y$ in range $[0,p)$ such that $g^x-y$ is a multiple of $p$. That $y$ is an integer, and we want it to be the given $a$.

#### Range check of $a$

It follows that there can be a solution to $a=g^x\bmod p$ only if $a$ is an integer in $[0,p)$. In the following we'll assume this has been checked to hold.

#### Search by enumeration

Notice that for all $n\in\mathbb N$, it holds $g^{n+1}\bmod p=((g^n)\cdot g)\bmod p=(g^n\bmod p)\cdot g\bmod p$. This gives an efficient mean to compute $G_n=g^n\bmod p$ for incremental values of $n\in\mathbb N$, using that $G_0=1$ and the recurrence relation $G_{n+1}=G_n\cdot g\bmod p$. E.g.

- For $(g,p)=(2,11)$ the sequence goes 1, 2, 4, 8, 5, 10, 9, 7, 3, 6, 1, 2, 4, …
- For $(g,p)=(2,10)$ the sequence goes 1, 2, 4, 8, 6, 2, 4, 8, 6, 2, …
- For $(g,p)=(3,10)$ the sequence goes 1, 3, 9, 7, 1, 3, 9, …
- For $(g,p)=(2,8)$ the sequence goes 1, 2, 4, 0, 0, 0, …

That sequence $G_n$ consists of integers in $[0,p)$, thus is bound to cycle at one of it's earlier values after at worst $p$ steps. Thus a basic algorithm to solve for $x$ the equation $a=g^x\bmod p$ is:

- $x\gets 0$ and $G\gets 1$
- while $x<p$

  - if $G=a$ then output "the smallest non-negative integer solution is " $x$, and stop.
  - $x\gets x+1$ and $G\gets G\cdot g\bmod p$
- output "there is no solution", and stop.

In the worst case, this algorithm performs $p$ multiplication modulo $p$, thus has worst-case time complexity $\mathcal O(p\cdot\log^2p)$ using standard algorithms.

#### Composite $p$: Pohlig-Hellman

When $p$ is not a prime, and if we manage to fully factor $p$, we can use the [Pohlig-Hellman algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pohlig%E2%80%93Hellman_algorithm). In a nutshell, the algorithm uses that having factored $p$ as $\prod{p_i}^{m_i}$, the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) allows to break the original equation $g^x\bmod p=a$ into simpler subproblems ${g_i}^x\bmod{p_i}^{m_i}=A_i$ with $g_i=g\bmod{p_i}^{m_i}$ and $A_i=a\bmod {p_i}^{m_i}$.

In the following I'll restrict to $p$ prime.

#### Prime $p$: further check of $a$, and a slight simplification

When $p$ is prime, the values taken by $G_n$ as defined above always cycle back at $1$, and first do so when $n$ is a certain integer defined as the order of $g$ modulo $p$, often noted $|g|$. That $|g|$ is such that $g^{|g|}\bmod p=1$ (and the smallest strictly positive such integer).

By [Lagrange's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_(group_theory)) of group theory, $|g|$ is always a divisor of $p-1$. If we can factor $p-1$, we can compute $|g|$ reasonably efficiently. The general idea uses that we can compute $g^n\bmod p$ ([modular exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation)) with only $\mathcal O(\log n)$ modular multiplications. This allows checking $g^{(p-1)/k}\bmod p=1$ for various $k$. We first do so for $k=q_i$ among the primes dividing $p-1$, and if $g^{(p-1)/k}\bmod p\ne1$ for every of these we conclude that $|g|=p-1$; or, if we find a $k$ with $g^{(p-1)/k}\bmod p\ne1$, we can proceed with larger multiples of $k$ until we find $|g|$.

More often than not, $|g|$ is sizably smaller than $p$; sometime, much smaller. For example, when $(p,g)$ are chosen as in [Clauss P. Schnorr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Claus_P._Schnorr)'s [Efficient Signature Generation by Smart Cards](https://schnorrsig.grieu.fr/), $p$ might have 155 decimal digits, but $|g|$ might have "only" 43 decimal digits†.

Knowing $|g|$ lets us perform a quick test to determine if there is a solution: there's one if and only if $a^{(p-1)/|g|}\bmod p=1$. Thus an alternate algorithm is:

- if $a^{(p-1)/|g|}\bmod p\ne 1$, then output "there is no solution", and stop.
- $x\gets 0$ and $G\gets 1$
- while $G\neq a$

  - $x\gets x+1$ and $G\gets G\cdot g\bmod p$
- output "the smallest non-negative integer solution is " $x$, and stop.

Worst case complexity for known factorization of $p$ is $\mathcal O(|g|\cdot\log^2p+\log^4p)$ with $|g|<p$, for standard algorithms.

#### Baby-step/giant-step

Assume we know $|g|$. The baby-step/giant-step algorithm works as follows:

- if $a^{(p-1)/|g|}\bmod p\ne 1$, then output "there is no solution", and stop.
- $r\gets\left\lceil{\sqrt{|g|}}\,\right\rceil$
- $i\gets 0$ and $y\gets a$
- repeat

  - enter $y$ and $i$ in a table allowing quick search of $y$ and determining the matching $i$
    [notice that here $y=a\cdot g^i\bmod p$ ]
  - if $i=r-1$ then exit the repeat loop
  - $i\gets i+1$ and $X\gets a\cdot g$
- $z\gets g^r\bmod n$ (by modular exponentiation)
- $j\gets 0$ and $y\gets 1$
- repeat until $y$ (and it's matching $i$) is found in the table

  - $j\gets j+1$ and $y\gets y\cdot z\bmod p$
- $x\gets j\cdot r-i\bmod|g|$
- output "the smallest non-negative integer solution is " $x$, and stop.

The first repeat loop advances by "baby steps" of one additional power of $g$. The second repeat loop advances by "giant steps" of $r$ additional powers of $g$. The algorithm works because when there's a match, $g^{j\cdot r}\bmod p=a\cdot g^i\bmod p$.

Assuming we know that $p$ is prime, and the order $|g|$, this algorithm has time complexity $\mathcal O(\sqrt{|g|}\cdot\log^2p+\log^3p)$ with $|g|<p$, for standard algorithms. That's a great improvement over search by enumeration thanks to replacing $|g|$ by $\sqrt{|g|}$. However the space complexity is $\mathcal O(\sqrt{|g|}\cdot\log p)$, and that makes it impractical for parameters of cryptographic interest.

#### Pollard's rho for discrete logarithm

The space complexity of baby-step/giant-step can be reduced down to the point of becoming a non-issue, by using collision search rather than a table. See wikipedia's [Pollard's rho for the discrete logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_rho_algorithm_for_logarithms). The time complexity remains similar to that in baby-step/giant-step.

For a more detailed analysis of the technique, and how it can be used to distribute the work over multiple CPUs, see Paul C. van Oorschot & Michael J. Wiener's [Parallel Collision Search with Cryptanalytic Applications](https://doi.org/10.1007/PL00003816), in JoC 1999.

That parallel version of Pollard's rho for discrete logarithm is the algorithm of choice in many cases of cryptographic interest, including Diffie-Hellman when the order $|g|$ is moderate (say up to 50 decimal digits) and $p$ is much larger. And also when, instead of multiplication modulo $p$, it's used another group operation, as is the case in [Elliptic Curve Cryptography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic-curve_cryptography).

#### Even better algorithms

In the case of multiplication modulo $p$, and when $|g|$ is not particularly small, there are even better algorithms: [Index calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_calculus_algorithm), and the [function field sieve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_field_sieve).

Parallel variants of the later have been [used](https://eprint.iacr.org/2020/697) for $p$ of up to 240 decimal digits, and $|g|$ not particularly small.

---

† Such sizes of $p$ and $|g|$ was borderline safe in the 1990s, and no longer is safe. Nowadays (2022), for new applications, 2048-bit or 3072-bit $p$ (617 or 925 decimal digits) and at least 256-bit $|g|$ (≈77 decimal digits) are customary, in order to resist both the function field sieve and parallel Pollard's rho.