# EL Gamal Attack without a secret key

Tags: encryption, elgamal-encryption

I have the following data where all the inputs are Big Integers,

1. group size $p$,
2. group generator $g$
3. public key of the receiver $y$
4. $c_1$ and $c_2$
5. Random Number as well

I am trying to execute an EL Gamal Attack (On a Weak Number Generator) without knowing the secret key $x$.

$$y = g^x \bmod p\quad  \text{where } x \text{ is the secret key.}$$

As we know $y,g$ and $p$. I am trying to compute $x$.I tried as follows $m$ as,

$$m = c_2 \times (c_1^x )^{-1}$$

By converting $m$ as ByteArray, I am not getting the desired output!

- What I am missing out? What's the advantage of having this random number as input?

Actually,I tried finding x by taking log on both sides,

> log y = x log g mod p

Each y, g, and P are of 1024 bits. Java is not supporting this `BigInteger` computation. How can I solve this equation involving such a big number?

Or is there any other shortcut available to compute the secret key, if the public key and g are given? Also, how can I take advantage of the given random number?

Comment: Cool! The Edit is impressive! Thanks !! Yeah, this is part of my home work . I read and tried the implementation already. Just I want some help to evaluate if I am doing something wrong here!

Comment: Each g, p, and y are of length 308. How can I compute x accurately from the equation, as  Big Integers of length 308 are  involved

Comment: Probably best to remove the question from StackOverflow, or leave just the question about `BigInteger` there :)

Comment: I gave a broad tag Cryptography in StackOverflow that should put my question in the eyes of many people. So looking forward for some quick attention.

Comment: Finally Did it! I used the public key inverse and the random number to compute my shared secret key! However Thanks everyone for all your suggestions!

Comment: You are looking for the [discrete log](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/76230/18298) and that is a hard problem.

Answer (score 1):

> $g$, $p$, and $y$ are of length 308 (decimal digits). How can I compute $x$ accurately from the equation?

Computations with integers this size (for example, verifying a guess of an integer $x$) are possible with [Python's `pow`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#pow) in its three-arguments form, [Java's `BigInteger modPow`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#modPow(java.math.BigInteger,%20java.math.BigInteger)), GP/Pari, Sage, Mathematica…

> I tried finding $x$ by taking log on both sides

That method can give you a *real* $x$, but here we want an integer. Given 1024-bit prime $p$, generator $g$, and $y=g^x\bmod p$, there is no general and easy way to find an integer $x$. That *may* be possible if the [order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_(group_theory)) of $g$ is appropriately [smooth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smooth_number), but nothing in the context suggests that. That also *may* be possible if $x$ was generated by a weak RNG, but since the nature of the weakness is untold, it is hard to tell how to proceed.

> 5. Random Number as well

Perhaps that mysterious given helps to determine the nature of the RNG weakness. Or/and perhaps this given is somewhat related to the random number generated during the encryption, which knowledge would trivially allow to decipher without the private key $x$.