# Which groups are secure for DL-Problem?

Tags: threshold-cryptography

I was wondering why some groups provide more security to cryptosystems relying on DL-Problem.

Comment: Welcome to crypto.SE. Hint for your research towards this apparent assignment: find what the DLP is in the group $(\mathbb Z_n,+)$, and solve it using e.g. the [extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) or the slightly simplified variant [there](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/54477/555). Then consider the group $(\Bbb Z_p^*,*)$ and the impact of [index calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_calculus_algorithm) and [GNFS for the DLP](https://listserv.nodak.edu/cgi-bin/wa.exe?A2=NMBRTHRY;a0c66b63.1606).

Comment: You may want to have a look at https://safecurves.cr.yp.to/. They introduce some notions about the security of elliptic curves.

Comment: This might be helpful, too. [Discrete Logarithm: Given a p, what does it mean to find the discrete logarithm of x to base y?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/76241/18298)