# Why is private key chosen to be less than chosen prime in diffie-hellman?

Tags: diffie-hellman

since the public key is calculated as Y=(alpha^private-key)mod(chosen prime) and alpha is a primitive root of prime, when Y becomes public then private key can be calculated easily right? since there is a unique private key less than chosen prime that will satisfy the equation. I think I'm missing something here. Please help.

Comment: Because that $x$ will be equal to $x \equiv t \pmod{chosen\, prime}$. Simple math course.

Comment: Read the answer by poncho.

Comment: Yes sir! I read it don't worry. Look at your title again and my comment, too. [dlog](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/76230/18298)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> since the public key is calculated as Y=(alpha^private-key)mod(chosen prime) and alpha is a primitive root of prime, when Y becomes public then private key can be calculated easily right?

One certainly hopes that it cannot be calculated easily, at least, for the 'chosen prime' that we pick.

> since there is a unique private key less than chosen prime that will satisfy the equation.

There's a difference between showing that the equation has a solution, and demonstrating that solution.  That the equation has a solution can be shown by relatively simple number theory; as for finding that solution, the best known algorithm [1] for solving it for unstructured [2] values of $p$ takes superpolynomial time, that is, it slows down (as larger values of $p$ are considered) faster than any polynomial.  The largest unstructured $p$ for which there is a published solved random discrete log problem is circa 768 bits long; we currently use values of $p$ that are at least 2048 bits long (and sometimes longer).

BTW: we generally don't use values of $\alpha$ that is a primitive root; we prefer values that have a large prime order, as that leaks less data about the private value we picked.

---

[1]: on a conventional computer (such as what you are using to read this web site).  There is a known algorithm that runs on a Quantum Computer which runs in polynomial time; however we currently don't have a Quantum Computer that's large enough and reliable enough to implement that algorithm).

[2]: it turns out to be an easily problem if $p-1$ doesn't have any large prime factors; we deliberately select the $p$ values we use in practice so that $p-1$ does have a large prime factor.

Comment: Thank You, i understood that though calculating the private key looks easy with small primes, it's unfeasible to calculate it for very large numbers. I hope i got it right.