# Time complexity of DLP over Elliptic curve group

Tags: elliptic-curves, discrete-logarithm

Consider NIST 192 elliptic curve group https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-186-draft.pdf. What is the time complexity
of discrete log problem of it? Is it Pollard $\rho$ i.e $\sqrt{N}$, where $N$ is the size of the group?

Comment: Welcome to Cryptography.SE What did you search [1](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/76230/18298)? Also, the question is lack of knowledge on $N$, is it prime or smooth number, or ...?

Comment: [P-192 is dead](https://www.secg.org/SEC2-Ver-1.0.pdf)

Comment: How? What is the attack complexity?

Comment: Parallel Pollard's $\rho$ did you read the necessary part on the links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Pollard's rho, in it's distributed version, is the best known method to break the DLP in the Elliptic Curve groups in NIST's [SP 800-186 (draft) section 4](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-186-draft.pdf#page=18) linked in the question, and NIST's [FIPS 186-4 appendix D](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.186-4.pdf#page=96) which specifies the P-192 curve alluded to in the question. It's also the method used in most¹ similar [record attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm_records#Elliptic_curves).

Work complexity is $\mathcal O(\sqrt n\,\log^2(n))$ where $n$ is the group order². Time for attack is $\mathcal O(\sqrt n\,\log^2(n)/d)$, where $d$ the number of devices running in parallel. Each device needs little memory.

The standard reference is Paul C. van Oorschot & Michael J. Wiener's [*Parallel Collision Search with Cryptanalytic Applications*](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/PL00003816.pdf), in [JOC, 1999](https://doi.org/10.1007/PL00003816).

---

¹ An exception is attacks where the secret private exponent thought is in an known interval, where Pollard's kangaroo has an edge. That can be viewed as a variant of Pollard's rho, and the asymptotic cost is not improved for the general case.

² The term $\log^2(n)$ reflects the cost of a group operation. That would be $\log^2(h\,n)$ in general, where $h$ is the cofactor. But $h=1$ for P-192, and $h\le8$ in all curves in the two NIST documents, so we can remove it from the equations.