# Cracking secret key, n, and m by hand with the Diffie-Hellman key exchange brute force

Tags: public-key, diffie-hellman, attack, brute-force-attack

Problem: You see Michael and Nikita agree on a secret key using the Diffie-Hellman key exchange. Michael and Nikita choose $p = 97$ and $g = 5$.
Nikita chooses a random number n and tells Michael that $g^n \equiv 3\pmod{97}$, and Michael chooses a random number $m$ and tells Nikita
that $g^m ≡ 7 \pmod{97}$. Brute force crack their code: What is the
secret key that Nikita and Michael agree upon? What is $n$? What
is $m$?

This is how the Diffie-Hellman exchange is defined in the textbook:

1. Together Michael and Nikita choose a 200-digit integer p that is likely
   to be prime, and choose a number $g$ with $1 < g < p$.
2. Nikita secretly chooses an integer $n$.
3. Michael secretly chooses an integer $m$.
4. Nikita computes $g^n \pmod{p}$ on her handheld computer and tells
   Michael the resulting number over the phone.
5. Michael tells Nikita $g^m \pmod{p}$.
6. The shared secret key is then $s\equiv g^{nm}\pmod{p}$
   which both Nikita and Michael can compute.

My thoughts/attempts: 
Attempt 1. I tried to find $n$ through solving the modular equation $5^n\equiv 3\pmod{97}.$ Then we have $n\equiv \log_53\pmod{97},$ which is not an integer and thus doesn't make sense. 
Attempt 2. I tried to find the key using $g^n$ and $g^m.$ However, I don't see a way to reach $g^{nm}$ since $g^ng^m = g^{n+m},$ and we cannot calculate $(g^n)^m$ or $(g^m)^n$ without knowing $m$ or $n,$
which from Attempt 1 I can't find integers for. 
 
Would appreciate help! Thank you

Comment: Attempt 1 is on the right track. It should be noted that, the logarithm is discrete, so the real number log function is not applicable here. It should be an integer, and as you said, otherwise it doesn't make sense.

Comment: How can you solve it if it's a discrete log?

Comment: Brutal-force (trying one by one) is good for small numbers like that in your exercise. Hackers would use mathematical techniques such as Pollard-rho or general number field sieve (GNFS).

Comment: @DannyNiu Oh, hence the "brute force" in the exercise!

Comment: With a small program while constructing the [the index table](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/76241/18298) find your desired value.